# How to create a link/button "more info" next to product names on cateory pages in Prestashop? (this should redirect to the product page)

Tags: module, prestashop, product

I have tried to edit the page "cateogory.tpl" trying to add a "more info" button next to products names with the ID of the products that redirects to the product page, but i can't find how to get it. Should I edit another module instead of "category.tpl"? (They are my first steps in Prestashop with my first project)

Answer (score 0):

For **Prestashop 1.6** you can edit file located at :

```
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-1.6/blob/master/themes/default-bootstrap/product-list.tpl

At line 117 you can find product name and link.
```

And for **Prestashop 1.7** file located at :

```
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/themes/classic/templates/catalog/_partials/miniatures/product.tpl

At line 48 you can find the block of product name and link.
```